# How to change all interface values in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface

If I have an function that accept a dynamic object as a param.

`const fun = <IValues>(values: IValues) => // IValues = {a: '', b: ''}`

I would like to use that object and a clone that has the same keys but different values:

```
//manage values to init valuesModified1 and valuesModified2
const originalValues: IValues = valuesModified1; // {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
const modifiedValues = valuesModified2; // {a: true', b: false}
return {originalValues, modifiedValues}
```

my problem is that modifiedValues doesn't have the correct types.

Is there a way to clone an interface but changing all it key's values?

EDIT:
based on iY1NQ's answer, I just used `: { [key in keyof IValues]: boolean }` and errors are gone (maybe is not the best solution but it's a solution):

```
const fun = <IValues>(values: IValues) => // IValues = {a: '', b: ''}
    //manage values to init valuesModified1 and valuesModified2

    const originalValues: IValues = valuesModified1; // {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
    const modifiedValues: { [key in keyof IValues]: boolean }  = valuesModified2; // {a: true', b: false}
    return {originalValues, modifiedValues}
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `IValues`?

Comment: Note: It's odd to use a defined type (`IValues`) as a generic parameter name.

Comment: *"my problem is that initVal2 doesn't have the correct types."* There is no `initVal2` in your code. Please show clearly your starting point, your full function definition (`fun` doesn't have any return type, for instance), and the result you want.

Comment: `IValues` is an object of string values with variable keys. you are right, I copied what I considered the important part and forgot to rename `initVal2`, `: { [key in keyof IValues]: T }` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That changes the type of each property to a new one specified by `T`:

```
const fun = <IValues, T>(values: IValues): { [key in keyof IValues]: T } => { 
    return ...;
} 

const result = fun<{ a: string }, boolean>({ a: "a"}); // => result: { a: boolean }
```

Comment: It's not the exact solution I'm looking for but solved my problem (setting the types to the "modifiedValues" did the trick